# Filtrar con queryset para mostrar a un usuario solo sus registros

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hola soy nuevo en Django y necesito un poco de ayuda, estoy creando un sistema de tickets y necesito hacer que al loggearse se muestren solamente los proyectos y tickets realizados solamente por ese cliente, pero no logro hacer la relación.

P.D. El sistema está relacionado de usuario a cliente, de cliente a proyectos y de proyectos a tickets.

Esto es lo que tengo, espero y me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias:

```
def ticketShow(request):
    tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
    tickets=Ticket
       
    if request.method == "GET":
       #tickets=Ticket
        id = request.GET.get('ticket_id')
        if Ticket.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
           ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(id=id).get()
           return render(request, 'support/viewTicket.html' ,{'tickets':ticket})
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Ticket no existente')


class Client(models.Model):#modelo de cliente
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Usuario', related_name='client_user')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre' , max_length=255 )
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Codigo cliente', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email', max_length=75, unique= True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name='Telefono', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Creacion',auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Ultima Actualizacion',auto_now= True)
    

    
class Project(models.Model):
    namep= models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre de proyecto', max_length=255, default='NA')
    codeProject = models.CharField(verbose_name='Codigo de proyecto' , max_length=5, default='NA')
    codeClientFk = models.ForeignKey( Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Cliente')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Proyecto"
        ordering = ['namep']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.namep



class Ticket(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status',max_length=10)
    priodidad = models.CharField(verbose_name='Prioridad',max_length=10, default='alta', editable=False )
    dateCreated= models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de realizacion',auto_now_add = True)
    servicesAffected =  models.CharField(verbose_name='Servicios afectados',max_length=50)
    description =  models.CharField(verbose_name='Descripcion',max_length=200)
    codeProjectFk= models.ForeignKey( Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Codigo de proyecto')#fk project falta verbose_name
    imag = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Anexos", null=True, blank=True, upload_to="Ticket")#Añade una imagen aun falta agregar las imagenes,
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

Comment: Quieres que en la vista `ticketShow` se muestren los *tikets* y *proyectos* del usuario autenticado en ese momento?

Comment: Sí, solamente que no se como realizarlo.

Comment: Ok, acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar **todos** los tickets y proyectos del usuario autenticado en ese momento, tu vista debe ser así:

```
def ticketShow(request):
    user_projects = request.user.client_user.project_set.all()
    user_tikets = []

    for project in user_projects:
        user_tikets += [*project.ticket_set.all()]

    return render(request, 'support/viewTicket.html' , {
        'user_tikets': user_tikets, 
        'user_projects': user_projects
    })
```

Un usuario, se relaciona con un cliente (`request.user.cliente`), un cliente se relaciona con varios proyectos y a su ves dichos proyectos, con varios tickets.

Y en tu template, puedes mostrarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
{% for ticket in user_tikets %}
    <p>{{ ticket }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for project in user_projects %}
    <p>{{ project.namep }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Por otra parte, en tu vista haces esto, que no le encuentro sentido:

```
   if request.method == "GET":
       tickets=Ticket
        id = request.GET.get('ticket_id')
        if Ticket.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
           ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(id=id).get()
           return render(request, 'support/viewTicket.html' ,{'tickets':ticket})
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Ticket no existente')
```

Se supone que quieres obtener todos los tikets del usuario... y veo que estas filtrando los tikets en base a parámetros GET HTTP.

En todo caso, creo que esto estas intentando hacer o algo así (una versión mejorada de tu código):

```
def ticketShow(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id = request.GET.get('ticket_id'))

            user_projects = request.user.client_user.project_set.all()
            user_tikets = []

            for project in user_projects: user_tikets += [*project.ticket_set.all()]

            return render(request, 'support/viewTicket.html' , {
                'user_tikets': user_tikets, 
                'user_projects': user_projects,
                'ticket': ticket,
            })

        except Ticket.DoesNotExist: 
            return HttpResponse('Ticket no existente')
```

O puedes utilizar la función [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def ticketShow(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id = request.GET.get('ticket_id'))

        user_projects = request.user.client_user.project_set.all()
        user_tikets = []

        for project in user_projects: user_tikets += [*project.ticket_set.all()]

        return render(request, 'support/viewTicket.html' , {
            'user_tikets': user_tikets, 
            'user_projects': user_projects,
            'ticket': ticket,
        })
```

> La función `get_object_or_404` llama al metodo `get()` en un
> administrador de modelos determinado, pero genera una excepción
> `Http404` en lugar de la  `DoesNotExist` del modelo.

Es decir, si no existe el objeto, se genera una excepción `Http404`. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya pude hacerlo funcionar.